# Apache Livy : Could not find or load main class org.apache.livy.server.LivyServer

Tags: java, apache-spark, livy

I am trying to start Apache Livy 0.8.0 server on my windows 10 machine for spark 3.1.2 and hadoop 3.2.1. I am taking help from [here.](https://jtaras.medium.com/building-apache-livy-0-8-0-for-spark-3-x-9bdfe1a66bd7). I have successfully built apache livy using maven (I have attached a [image: screenshot] of it) But I am not able to run the livy server. When I run it I get the following error -

```
> starting C:/AmazonJDK/jdk1.8.0_332/bin/java  -cp /d/ApacheLivy/incubator-livy-master/incubator-livy-master/server/target/jars/*:/d/ApacheLivy/incubator-livy-master/incubator-livy-master/conf:D:/Program_files/spark/conf:D:/ApacheHadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/etc/hadoop: org.apache.livy.server.LivyServer, logging to D:/ApacheLivy/incubator-livy-master/incubator-livy-master/logs/livy--server.out
ps: unknown option -- o
Try `ps --help' for more information.
failed to launch C:/AmazonJDK/jdk1.8.0_332/bin/java  -cp /d/ApacheLivy/incubator-livy-master/incubator-livy-master/server/target/jars/*:/d/ApacheLivy/incubator-livy-master/incubator-livy-master/conf:D:/Program_files/spark/conf:D:/ApacheHadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/etc/hadoop: org.apache.livy.server.LivyServer:
  Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.livy.server.LivyServer
full log in D:/ApacheLivy/incubator-livy-master/incubator-livy-master/logs/livy--server.out
```

I am using Git bash. If you need more information I will provide

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: Your Java command is using a Windows path, but then referencing /d/ folder paths... Something in your path is misconfigured and you should only need CMD, not Git bash. Although WSL2 might work better, overall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error got resolved when I used Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).